# Searching an String array for a sub-string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, search, indexof

I am trying to write a little method in java, but I cannot figure it out. What I want to be able to do is enter a string, and then the value of an int variable is set to the index of this in the array, i.e if I have an array consisting of

```
[0] 'hi guys'
[1] 'this'
[2] 'is'
[3] 'sparta'
```

The value of my integer is set at 0, and I want to find the first occurrence of "ta", which will be [3], so I want the function to set my integer to 3.

What I have at the moment is completely off the wall and wrong, is there any simple way of doing this ? I already have a function called get() defined which returns the value of the current line (i.e get(0) in this case would return 'hi guys'). Can anyone help me out please ?

Thanks a lot :)

```
 public void find(String line ) {
   boolean found = false;
   int i = cursor + 1;
   while ( found = false && i!=cursor) {
   if ((doc.get(cursor).indexOf( line ) > 0)){
  cursor = i;
  found = true;
   }else {
    cursor++;
    cursor%=doc.size();
    i++;

   }
 }
 }
```

Comment: IS this homework? If so, you should tag it as such.

Comment: @steveom: You're definitely in the weeds here but to help you out we'll need some info: Where is the text data coming from that you want to put in the array and search? What type of object is doc right now? Are you attempting to read a file?

Comment: @steveom: There are also some glaring errors and omissions: `found = false` should be `found == false` You're assigning it right now instead of comparing. I also don't see anyplace where you're actually searching a line for a substring... From your example: ` find the first occurrence of "ta"`

Comment: @Paul Sasik, fixed the equals problem. doc is an instant of a class I defined, with all the basic functionality of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood your task correctly, I would do something like:

```
public int find(String line, int startPosition) {
    if (doc[startPosition].contains(line) {
        return startPosition;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(doc.size() - startPosition, startPosition); i++) {
        if (startPosition - i > 0 && doc[startPosition - i].contains(line)) {
            return startPosition - i;
        }
        if (startPosition + i < doc.size() && doc[startPosition + i].contains(line)) {
            return startPosition + i;
        }

    }
    return -1;
}
```

This would return an index of the first element in the array that contains the substring passed as line parameter.

Comment: This may be pretty close but i think the OP needs to do a substring search on each line:  From the question `find the first occurrence of "ta"` which is a substring of 3rd example entry.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, Paul. I need to search every line for the substring. The main issue I am having problems with is that I have a value, let's call it i, which is pointing at the array, and may be pointing at a position in the middle of the array, I want to traverse the array and find nearest index to i, into the array where the substring exists. Sorry, I couldn't make that clear before !

Comment: Ok, what I implemented above does search for a substring so I'm not sure what Paul is talking about. Now it does return _first_ index in the array that corresponds to a string that contains substring passed as a parameter whereas it seems there should be another parameter and the index should be the one that is the closest one to that parameter value. In that case, algorithm needs to be adjusted, I'm going to edit my original code appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander, I have ran this code with my class and it's much cleaner than what I was previously doing, it just needs a little bit of adaption :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Usually I dont do this, but today is Saturday and I am happy and probably going to get drunk

```
public void find(String line ) {
   boolean found = false;
   int i = 0;;
   while (i < doc.size()) {
     if ((doc.get(i).indexOf( line ) > 0)){
       cursor = i;
       found = true;
       break;
     }else {
       i++;
     }
   }
   if (found) {
      // print cursor or do whatever
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should note if this is homework.

One way to do this is:

```
    int i = 0;
    String searchTerm = "ta";

    System.out.println("Following substrings contain search term:");
    for (String s : "hi guys,this,is,sparta".split(",")) {
        if (s.contains(searchTerm)) System.out.println(i++);
        else i++;
    }
```

Or if you prefer using regex, then change `s.contains(searchTerm)` with  `s.matches(searchTerm)`.

If this is not homework, but interview question or work problem, this would be vastly more complex. For example: aminoacid sequence is search term and need to find locations in DNA/RNA where it is located. In that case you need more complex solution.

Examples:

- [Brute-Force String Matching](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BruteForceStringMatching/)
- [Suffix Trees String Matching Algorithm](http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/) ( wiki )
- [Boyer-Moore String Matching Algorithm](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/bmen.htm) ( [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) )
- [Knuth-Morris-Pratt String Matching](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/kmpen.htm) ( [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) )
- [Sunday String Matching  algorithm](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/sundayen.htm) ( wiki )
- [Horspool String Matching algorithm](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/horsen.htm) ( wiki )
- Rabin-Karp string matching algorithm ( [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm) )
- Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm  ( [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) )

Answer (score 1):

He says this is not homework, so here it is:

(this actually compiles and works)

```
    import java.io.*;

    public class A {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                    String[] arr = {"hi guys", "this", "is", "sparta"};
                    System.out.println("enter substring:");
                    String substr = "";
                    try {
                    substr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
                    } catch(IOException e) {System.exit(0);}
                    for(int i =0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                            int charPos = arr[i].indexOf(substr);
                            if(charPos!=-1) {
                                    System.out.println("found in string index " + i + " at "+charPos);
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

would’t it be more sensible to search in the actual string[] instead of each line?

then you loop over the array and return the current index if the string at this position contains the substring.